# gdb: print doesn't recognize variables with non-standard names or characters?

Tags: gdb

I'm writing a little BASIC compiler using LLVM, everything works fine. I'm trying to get debugging to work, and it's going fine, but I have a weird issue with variable names and GDB's print statement.

A little background on BASIC for those not familiar:

> In BASIC, variable names use a symbol on the end to determine their type. So a variable x% would be integer, and variable x$ would be a string, and both can co-exist.
>
> The statement DEFINT A-Z means that any variable starting with any letter from A to Z will     be type INT, even without the trailing %.  But, internally, my compiler will store the name mangled with the trailing % to avoid overlap with another variable with a trailing $.

Here is my little test program:

```
defint a-z

x = 5
y = 100
z = x + y
if x = 5 then
  print "z=";z
else
  print "z!=";z
end if
```

So 'x' is actually stored internally and put into the symbol table as x%.

OK, so I load my compiled EXE into GDB...

```
D:\dev\BasicParser>gdb t.exe
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-pc-mingw32".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from D:\dev\BasicParser\t.exe...done.
(gdb) b _jbc_main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x401000: file t.bas, line 1.
(gdb) r
Starting program: D:\dev\BasicParser\t.exe
[New Thread 1532.0x25b8]

Breakpoint 1, _jbc_main () at t.bas:1
1       defint a-z
(gdb) n
4       x = 5
(gdb) info address x%
Symbol "x%" is static storage at address 0x4263c4.
```

At this point, you can see that GDB recognizes the symbol x% because it recognizes and display it's address.  But the following "print" fails:

```
(gdb) print x%
No symbol "x" in current context.
```

Hmmm... that's interesting ... it dropped the % symbol.

But I can look at the memory location where x% is stored and this looks correct:

```
(gdb) x 0x4263c4
0x4263c4 <x%>:  0x00000000
```

If I show all symbols I get this as expected:

```
(gdb) info variables
All defined variables:

File t.bas:
static i32 x%;
static i32 y%;
static i32 z%;
```

Continuing on, to show that x% does get modified by the code:

```
(gdb) n
5       y = 100
(gdb) print x%
No symbol "x" in current context.
(gdb) x 0x4263c4
0x4263c4 <x%>:  0x00000005
(gdb)
```

And as you can see, the memory that GDB thinks x% is at is definitely updated.

For some reason, the "print" command doesn't like the % symbol.

Here is the "info source" results on this module, you can see I didn't specify C as the language:

```
(gdb) info source
Current source file is t.bas
Compilation directory is D:\dev\BasicParser
Located in D:\dev\BasicParser\t.bas
Contains 18 lines.
Source language is minimal.
Compiled with DWARF 2 debugging format.
Does not include preprocessor macro info.
```

Any ideas for workarounds? I've been searching and searching and can't find a solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gdb` simply interprets your command as modulo operation. It is not an error in `gdb`.

See, `info source` shows `minimal` for your file. This is from gdb's doc: http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Unsupported-Languages.html#Unsupported-Languages

> In addition to the other fully-supported programming languages, GDB
>   also provides a pseudo-language, called `minimal`. It does not represent
>   a real programming language, but provides a set of capabilities close
>   to what the C or assembly languages provide.

So, what does this warning in your debugging session mean?

```
(gdb) print x%
No symbol "x" in current context.
```

Since `minimal` is a set of capabilities close C then `gdb` must iterpret this as trying to get remainder of division (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) - according to C programming language rules. So `x` is left arg, `%` is operation and the right arg is missing.

Let me show you example. This is a test C++ program that shows the `minimal` debugging session:

```
D:\src-c++\tests\test.vars>cat minimal.cpp

int main()
{
  int k;
  k = 1;
  k = 2;
  return 0;
}
```

And this is a debugging session:

```
D:\src-c++\tests\test.vars>gdb -q minimal.exe
Reading symbols from D:\src-c++\tests\test.vars\minimal.exe...done.
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x4016be: file minimal.cpp, line 5.
Starting program: D:\src-c++\tests\test.vars/minimal.exe
[New Thread 2872.0x8c0]

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at minimal.cpp:5
5         k = 1;
(gdb) show language
The current source language is "auto; currently c++".
(gdb) set language minimal
Warning: the current language does not match this frame.
(gdb) show language
The current source language is "minimal".
Warning: the current language does not match this frame.
(gdb) n
6         k = 2;
(gdb) print k
$1 = 1
(gdb) print k%
A syntax error in expression, near `'.
(gdb) print kk%
No symbol "kk" in current context.
```

Look -- No symbol "kk" in current context, the same error that you have.

Comment: OK, thanks, that makes sense as to 'why'... but the question is, how can I get around it?  I understand that 'print' has an expression as it's arguments, so you can do print 2+3+x, but is there a way to see the value of a valid symbol name like 'x%' that isn't compatible with the print expression format/syntax?

Comment: Frankly, I don't think it is possible to use `print` for a variable that is incompatible with the syntax of the current language. `gdb` supports some languages: http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Supported-Languages.html#Supported-Languages but not the one what you need. I think you have to keep using `info address` and `x` to inspect your vars.

Answer (score 1):

Just a cross-reference, in case anybody else like me that might need help with this: I found this answer

[In GDB, how to print the content of a symbol which has special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61507770/in-gdb-how-to-print-the-content-of-a-symbol-which-has-special-characters)

where they indicate that you can quote names by starting with ampersand (`&`) and quote the name with single ticks (`'`), that is use something like

```
p &'my@complex.symbol%name'
x &'my@complex.symbol%name'
```

to inspect symbols with names beyond the usual C-style naming convention. I'm not completely clear what characters you can use at that point, but it seems like a good improvement.

As the other answer also points out, the GDB manual often refers to escaping symbol names just using single ticks (say something like `p 'foo.c'`). After some further reading I found in the GDB manual that this use of `&` seems to be an extension added for Windows support (see section titled "Features for Debugging MS Windows PE Executables", numbered 21.1.4 in the current edition), so I'm not sure if this may work outside of the Windows environment