# In GDB, how to print the content of a symbol which has special characters?

Tags: gdb

I encounter a small problem when debugging with GDB.
The problem is like this:

When I want to get the address of 'main', I can do

```
gdb-peda$ p main
$1 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x400b21 <main>
gdb-peda$ x main
0x400b21 <main>:        0x000000b8e5894855
```

But if I want to get the address of 'puts@got.plt', it becomes

```
gdb-peda$ x puts@got.plt
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
gdb-peda$ p puts@got.plt
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
```

And 'puts@got.plt' actually exists.

```
gdb-peda$ x 0x602020
0x602020 <puts@got.plt>:        0x00000000004006e6
```

I think I have to escape '@' and '.' such that the information of 'puts@got.plt' can be printed out successfully, but I don't know how to do. Can anyone help me?

------ 2020/05/03 edited ------

Thank @JohnKoch, I tried `x &'puts@got.plt'`, it works.

Although I can't figure out why it does not just print the content of `'puts@got.plt'` when using `x 'puts@got.plt'`, such that I need to add `&`......

```
gdb-peda$ x/4gx 'puts@got.plt'
0x7ffff7a649c0 <_IO_puts>:      0x55fc894954415541      0x072ee808ec834853
0x7ffff7a649d0 <_IO_puts+16>:   0x36be6f2d8b48fffa      0x4800458bc3894800
```

Add `&`:

```
gdb-peda$ x/4gx &'puts@got.plt'
0x602020 <puts@got.plt>:        0x00007ffff7a649c0      0x00000000004006f6
0x602030 <printf@got.plt>:      0x0000000000400706      0x0000000000400716
```

Comment: What about simply `x puts`?

Comment: put `puts@got.plt` in between single quote? Like this, `p 'puts@got.plt'`

Comment: @MrBens After I tried, `x puts` will print content of `puts@plt` before the got of `puts` resolved, and will print content of `_IO_puts` after resolved. It still can't print content of `puts@got.plt`.

Comment: @JohnKoch `p 'puts@got.plt'` will print the content of `puts@plt` or `_IO_puts`, it is so strange, I don't know why. But I tried `p &'puts@got.plt'`, it surprisingly works, printing the content of `0x602020`. Cool, thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes like this:

```
(gdb) p 'my weird symbol'
```